# Access to existing html

Tags: reactjs

How to handle click on existing html anchor in react?

For example: 
Before react loading we got code like this

```html
<a href="/some_href" onClick={react should execute me}>click me</a>
<div id="root"></div>
```

```js
// App Component should contains logic for click listener 
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root')
```

So, is it possible to interact with existing html dom in react or it only provides the ability to work with rendered inside react components?

Answer (score 0):

It is, as far as I know, not possible to do what you ask.

The best workaround I can think of would be something like this:

```
<div id="root">
  <a href="/some_href">click me</a>
</div>
```

```
ReactDOM.render(<App>
  <a href="/some_href" onClick={react should execute me}>click me</a>
</App>, document.getElementById('root')
```

The original link would be removed as soon as React mounts, and replaced with a similar one wired to React.